# How to validate that password field is empty or not?

Tags: validation, email, passwords

```
public void onMyButtonClick1(View view)  
{  
     final EditText emailValidate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailid); 

        final TextView passValidate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.password); 

        String email = emailValidate.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass= passValidate.getText().toString().trim();

        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";


        // onClick of button perform this simplest code.
        if (email.matches(emailPattern)&&(passValidate!=null))
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this,"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome To Sun Telematics", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent getStarted = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FourthActivity.class);
        startActivity(getStarted);

            /*else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Field Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
        }


       else 
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}
```

I want to check that password field is empty or not. If it is empty it will not go to the next activity. It will show toast message.
I can validate that field. Where can i do the changes in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't check if the instance of the password field is null but whether the string content is actually empty or not. There are various utility libraries for this but it would probably suffice to check `!"".equals(pass)`

Note that by putting the "" up front you will avoid a `NullPointerException` even if your string could be null. In this case it wouldn't matter since you already got the string and trimmed it.

I recommend using StringUtils in the common lang library by Apache to handle this kind of stuff though, you could just write StringUtils.isNotEmpty(pass) in that case and it has various utility methods for checking whitespaces, converting strings, etc.

Comment: Bas van den simply tell me where can i change or modify in the above code. I don't know much about programming.

Comment: Honestly, this code is quite a mess, with comments placed here and there. I am not sure what it should actually achieve. For one I don't understand why it is checking if passvalidate != null in a part that appears to tell you the email address is valid and then seems to logs you in. If this is something you wrote yourself I would recommend doing a good tutorial on Java. Without understanding the code I could not tell you where to insert this code exactly.